# How to Split data into multiple sheets in one single workbook by country column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull data from a table and load into a excel workbook, i want to separate data by country and each country data will be loaded into each sheet with country name. But unfortunately i am didnt find exact logic to achieve this scenario. I need help here with errors and code to fix.Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('meddevices_tm.xlsx') as writer:
    dftm = pd.read_excel('')
    dbconnect = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=digital-dbserver.database.windows.net;Database=gdmd-db;uid=adm;pwd=gr!")
    tsql= 'select [Franchise Name],[Prod Number],[Product Description],[Net Content],[Net Content UOM],[Product Type],[Base Unit Indicator],[Dispatch Unit Indicator],[Invoice Unit Indicator],[Ordering Unit Indicator],[Country] from [dbo].[onews_med_devices] '
    cursor= dbconnect.cursor()
    dftm =pd.read_sql(tsql,dbconnect)
    dftm = pd.read_excel('Med Devices0818.xlsx')
    split_values = dftm['Country'].sort_values().unique()
    
    print(split_values)
    for value in split_values:
         print (value)
         (dftm.query(f'Country == {value}').drop(columns='Country').copy().to_excel(excel_writer=writer,sheet_name=f'Country{value}',index=False))
```

Comment: did you solve this? did it work with my answer? I'm only asking because there is another user asking the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63726617/6692898)

Comment: yes Richie, i took your group by and applied for my logi it worked for me. I tried to post the answer but the it was failed to submit in stake over flow because of format issue. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby`

```
for country, filtered_df in dftm.groupby('Country'):
    filtered_df.to_excel(...
```

This will return a filtered dataframe by each country, which you can save to a desired location.

Comment: i dont want to do any aggregations here. And can you elaborate this..

Comment: There are no aggregations. Groupby by itself does not aggregate, it merely creates an object that when iterated upon returns `(group_id, filtered_rows)`, each iteration can be treated as a separate df

Comment: Try printing `filtered_rows` on each iteration so you familiarize yourself with the output

Comment: Error:At least one sheet must be visible
for country, filtered_df in dftm.groupby('TargetMarket'):
        filtered_df.to_excel(writer)

Comment: with pd.ExcelWriter(r"D:\Users\TYarlaga\Documents\Med Devices0818.xlsx") as writer:
    dftm = pd.read_excel('')
    dbconnect = pyodbc.connect("")
    tsql= 'select *,[TargetMarket] from [dbo].[onews_med_devices] '
    cursor= dbconnect.cursor()
    dftm =pd.read_sql(tsql,dbconnect)
    split_values = dftm['TargetMarket'].sort_values().unique()
    for split_values, filtered_df in dftm.groupby('TargetMarket'):
        filtered_df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer,sheet_name=f'TargetMarket{split_value}',index=False)

Comment: The error probably comes from the `with pd.ExcelWriter(...` line, try adding parameter `mode='a'` for append

Comment: with pd.ExcelWriter(r"D:\Users\TYarlaga\Documents\Med Devices0818.xlsx",mode='a') as writer:
    dbconnect = pyodbc.connect("")
    tsql= 'select *,[TargetMarket] from [dbo].[onews_med_devices] '
    cursor= dbconnect.cursor()
    dftm =pd.read_sql(tsql,dbconnect)
    split_values = dftm['TargetMarket'].sort_values().unique()
      
    for split_values, filtered_df in dftm.groupby('TargetMarket'):
        filtered_df.to_excel(excel_writer=writer,sheet_name=f'TargetMarket{split_value}',index=False)
Error: BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: This is the below code which worked for me successfuly..
bconnect = pyodbc.connect("")
tsql= 'select *,[TargetMarket] from [dbo].[gd_devices] '
cursor= dbconnect.cursor()
dftm =pd.read_sql(tsql,dbconnect)
split_values = dftm['TargetMarket'].sort_values().unique()
print (split_values)
with pd.ExcelWriter(r"D:\gddevices_tm.xlsx",engine="openpyxl", mode = 'a') as writer:
    for split_values, filtered_df in dftm.groupby('TargetMarket'):
        filtered_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f'TargetMarket{split_values}',index=False)